# Inertia of a falling weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, collision, estimation, inertia

I use a standard device (penetrometer) that uses a 10 kg weight that is dropped a constant distance to cause a probe to penetrate soil. The penetration distance after 4 blows is recorded. If I were to use a 9 kg weight and increase the distance by 10% would the force being exerted be the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 blows"?

Comment: @Allure i think he means the mass hits the probe 4 times.

Comment: Yes - this is a standard method to measure bearing capacity of soils in geotechnical engineering. Strong soils will have a penetration of < 100 mm after 4 drops of the weight. The standard hammer weight is 9 kg that falls 510 mm. I have a weight of 10 kg so I am trying to calculate what falls distance would result in the same force as the 9 kg hammer/weight.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are getting somewhere. Please see following for an image of the device. Mine uses a 9 kg weight and a 20 mm D cone tip: https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/pavement-dynamic-cone-penetrometer-18361717130.html.

Comment: Now for some further questions.  The steel spear on my device is 3.2 kg in weight. This is built to engineering standards.  Now I want to add extensions, each being 1.2 m long and weighing 2.2 kg/ length. I will use up to 4 sections. Question: What difference to the force/energy being imposed on the soil will each additional section make? Is force/energy being absorbed by the extra weight of the extensions? ( i.e; they are of  a mass that needs to be accelerated) If so how much extra travel (h) must I add to the hammer travel/ each 2.2 kg extension?

Answer (score 1):

Well then we know $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ when you throw the weight. The impulse is $mv/\delta t = m\sqrt{2gh}/\delta t$ where $\delta t$ is time of contact regarded as same in both cases. Now in first case $10\sqrt{2gh}$ and in second $9\sqrt{2.2gh}$ [h*110/100= 1.1h] so clearly $10\sqrt2 >9\sqrt{2.2}$ so in the first case the probe will feel more fore hence more soil entering. And as well as the soil would offer a resistance of a then the penetration is $u^2/2g$ which would be more in first case rather than the second even after 4 blows. **** in case if you want to get at what height the 9 kg and the 10 kg make the same impact( or give the same force). then: $momentum_1=momentum_2${as $\delta t $ is same in both cases. $10\sqrt{2gh}= 9\sqrt{2g(h+x)}$  upon solving this we get $x=\frac{19h}{81}$ so for example if you make the 10 kg fall from 81 cm then 9kg has to fall from a height of 81+ (19/81)*81=100 cm to have same force on the probe. ******Now in case if your 9kg hammer falls 510mm then $h\times (1+19/81)= 510$ upon calculating for height of 10 kg i get 413.1 mm. **So by making the 10 kg hammer  fall 413.1 mm would apply same force as you 9kg hammer galling from 510mm.**